# How do I store JWT Token after receiving from Cognito? Logging in via the Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, token, amazon-cognito

Architecture: front end Angular, backend nodejs/express.

Currently the setup works as follow:

1. Login to the site via the Cognito Hosted UI
2. This redirects to our home page and sends us a code in the URL
3. I pull down this code in Angular

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DbService } from '../db.service';
import { Iss } from '../db.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard'
})
export class GroupSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  cognitoCode: string;

  constructor(
    private DbService: DbService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
    ) {}



  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
      console.log(params.code);
      this.cognitoCode = params.code;
    });  

  this.DbService.getIss(this.cognitoCode).subscribe(
    iss => this.iss = iss
    
    
  );

}
```

In the code you will see I am passing the congitocode to the dbservice for getIss.

**db.service**

```js
getIss(cognitoCode ): Observable<Issuer[]> {
  const url = hosturl +'i_l';
  // let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': cognitoCode 
    })
  };
  let params = new HttpParams()
  console.log(httpOptions.headers);
  return this._http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <Issuer[]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

I then send the code as part of the headers of my GET request to the backend.

The GET then hits my backend router with these settings.

```
var authMiddleware = require('../middleware/AuthMiddleware.js');
router.get('/i_l', authMiddleware.Validate, i_l.get);
```

This will then call my authMiddleware which takes the code provided by Cognito Hosted UI and use a POST against oauth2/token to get my JWT token.

That token is then parsed used to compare to the https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/REMOVED/.well-known/jwks.json for congnito.

Once validated the request continues and I get data back from the backend.

```js
    // POST that trades the code for a token with cognito
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://REMOVED.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'client_id': 'CLIENTIDREMOVED',
    'code': req.headers['authorization'],
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost/group-selection'
  }
};


// First request gets the JSON request of the token using the POST above
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
    token = JSON.parse(response.body).access_token;
    //localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    // request pull down status based on validitiy of token
    request({
        url : `https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/REMOVED/.well-known/jwks.json`,
        json : true
     }, function(error, response, body){
         console.log('token: ' + token);
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            pems = {};
            var keys = body['keys'];
            for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                 var key_id = keys[i].kid;
                 var modulus = keys[i].n;
                 var exponent = keys[i].e;
                 var key_type = keys[i].kty;
                 var jwk = { kty: key_type, n: modulus, e: exponent};
                 var pem = jwkToPem(jwk);
                 pems[key_id] = pem;
            }
            var decodedJwt = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
                 if (!decodedJwt) {
                     console.log("Not a valid JWT token");
                     res.status(401);
                     return res.send("Not a valid JWT token");
                }
             var kid = decodedJwt.header.kid;
                 var pem = pems[kid];
                 if (!pem) {
                     console.log('Invalid token - decodedJwt.header.kid');
                     res.status(401);
                     return res.send("Invalid token - decodedJwt.header.kid");              
                 }
             jwt.verify(token, pem, function(err, payload) {
                     if(err) {
                         console.log("Invalid Token - verify");
                         res.status(401);
                         return res.send("Invalid token  - verify");
                     } else {
                          console.log("Valid Token.");
                          return next();
                     }
                });
        } else {
              console.log("Error! Unable to download JWKs");
              res.status(500);
              return res.send("Error! Unable to download JWKs");
        }
    });


});
```

**Quesiton** -- how I set this up so that the Token I get back continues for the user?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly then you are trying to validate all your apis through cognito user right?
Then you just need to do two things.

1. Add in header JWT token once you are getting after login. Just store into your application scope and pass everytime whenever any API is calling.

```
Auth.signIn(data.username, data.password)
        .then(user => {
         
          let jwkToken = user.getSignInUserSession().getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
          // Store above value in singletone object or application scope.
        })
        .catch(err => {
          //error
        });
```

Now When API is calling  pass  jwkToken as header.

2. Then Go AWS ApiGateWay Console and add into Authorizers.

Comment: Thank you for your response -- which portion of the code would this live in?

Comment: Are you taking about Authorizers ? Please point out. I implemented for my project and customize it. So definately there is some difference with your application. But if you need  code then I have to send you image or filtered code.